# Kendo Grid external filtering

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

I have applied external filtering to my kendo grid which works fine with a single textbox and a button. But now I need to add another text box and a button above the grid and based on the button clicked, call the respective method.

```
    //add 2 text boxes and 2 buttons  
    <div style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
    @Html.TextBox("compSearch", (string)TempData["searchString"], new { id = "txtCompanySearch", style = "width: 400px;" })
    <button id="searchButton" class="button" type="button" style="text-align:center;" onclick="searchAccounts()">
        <span>Search</span>
        <img src="~/Content/images/magnifier.png" />
    </button>
    <input type="hidden" id="hdnSrchString" value="@ViewBag.searchString" />

    @Html.TextBox("compSearchByMasterRateSheetId", (string)TempData["searchStringMRS"], new { id = "txtCompanySearchByMasterRateSheetId", style = "width: 400px;" })
    <button id="searchByMasterRateSheetIdButton" class="button" type="button" style="text-align:center;" onclick="searchAccountsMRS()">
        <span>Search By Master Rate Sheet ID</span>
        <img src="~/Content/images/magnifier.png" />
    </button>
    <input type="hidden" id="hdnSrchStringMRS" value="@ViewBag.searchStringMRS" />

</div>

<div class="k-content">



  @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Customer>()
                .Name("accountsGrid")
            .Columns(col =>
            {
                col.Bound(c => c.CustomerName).Title("Account").Width("30%");
                col.Bound(c => c.SourceSystemId).Title("B ID").Width("20%");
                col.Bound(c => c.AccountManager).Title("Account Manager").Width("30%");
                col.Bound(c => c.IsExternalQuotingEnabled).Title("External Quoting Enabled?").Width("20%");
            })
            .SetLevel3Defaults(Model)
            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                .Ajax()
                .Read(read => read.Action("GetCompanyInfo", "Home").Data("additionalData"))
                .PageSize(20)                  
            )
)
```

GetCompanyInfo calls the stored proc and additionalData reads the text in the 1st text box.

```
function additionalData() {
        return {
            searchString: $("#txtCompanySearch").val()
        }
    }
```

All this works for the 1st text box and button click. I need to read the 2nd box when the 2nd button is clicked and call the respective stored proc to update the stored proc. Please advise.

Comment: Please show the javascript for `function searchAccounts() {}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this scenario you can use a global variable that is set by either of the click handlers, and then used by additionalData().

Case 1: both boxes uses same extra data item

```
var searchTerm;
function handler1 () { searchTerm = $("#box1").val(); }
function handler2 () { searchTerm = $("#box2").val(); }
function additionalData() { return { searchString: searchTerm } }
```

Case 2: each box requires a different data item

```
var searchData;
function handler1 () { searchData = { searchString:    $("#box1").val()}; }
function handler2 () { searchData = { searchStringMRS: $("#box2").val()}; }
function additionalData() { return searchData; }
```

You will need to set the initial searchTerm or searchData to be appropriate for the initial page load.